# Flex HTTPService Progressbar

Tags: apache-flex, progress-bar, httpservice

How can I set a progress bar that may start when an HTTPService is sent and stop when the HTTPService ends?

I followed code given [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/482948#482948) but encountered following error:

> Type was not found or was not a
>   compile-time constant: ProgressWin.

Don't know whether ProgressWin.mxml is a component or module or what. I just created a new ProgressWin.mxml  file and pasted the code you posted but following error popped out before

```
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx=" http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="250" height="150" title="Progressive Window">
```

Error:

> Could not resolve  to
>   a component implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there is an extra space before each URL in the sample code.  For example:

```
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx=" http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="250" height="150" title="Progressive Window">
```

should be

```
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="250" height="150" title="Progressive Window">
```